FFMPEG FDKAAC and Python
Been banging my head against the wall for days on this. I'm writing a python program to take a 48kHz WAV file, convert it to 44.1kHz and encode it to HE-AAC via FDKAAC. FDK cannot convert to sample rates, so I'm using FFMPEG as the wrapper and piping it through FDKAAC. In a perfect world, I'd make a custom build of FFMPEG with FKD, but I've run into loads of issues on our Windows Server 2019 machine trying to build out FFMPEG, so I'm using vanilla FFMPEG with FDK piped in.
I can get the command to work perfectly from a command prompt:
ffmpeg -progress pipe:2 -i <INPUT_FILE> -f wav -ar 44100 - | fdkaac -p 5 -b 64000 -o <OUTPUT_FILE>

But when I try to split it in Python for a Popen, it tries to evaluate the arguments and fails because ffmpeg doesn't have a "-p" argument:
cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-progress', 'pipe:2', '-i', inFile, \
    '-f', 'wav', '-ar', '44100', '-', '|', \
    'fdkaac', '-p', '5', '-b', '64000', '-o', outFile]
fdkProcess = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            universal_newlines=True)
for line in fdkProcess.stdout:
    print(line)

RESULT:
Unrecognized option 'p'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

I'll admit, I don't fully understand the pipeline process, and how to split commands via the "|" flag, and have them properly feed into stdout for the subprocess function to work correctly. I'm fairly new to python, and very new to programmatically capturing the output of a process like ffmpeg.

IIRC the pipe operator | is a shell command(?) so you need shell=True keyword argument to your Popen call.
